# Create empty matrix using variables names in a list

Tags: loops, matrix, assign

As the title says I am currently trying to create many empty matrices using their names stored in a list. I have look around and read several posts but it does not help me that much. I have tried the following code.

```
list <- list("branch","warren","yep")

for (i in 1:length(list)){
  assign(list[i],c())
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not working? Thanks for your help and have a nice day